# Group 8x8 blocks using for loops in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to group 8x8 blocks of pixel data that I retrieve from BufferedImage.

1. `jpegPixels` is a 3D int array with height, width, and an RGB size (0=Red, 1=Green, 2=Blue).
2. `pixelMatrix` is a 2D int array with 8x8 block size

So far the code works because I get a resultant image back out. Below is a partial sample of the code that groups pixels into 8x8 (it only shows 2 rows because code is too long).

```
int [][][] jpegPixels = new int[h][w][3]; //h = height size, w = width size
int [][] pixelMatrix = new int [8][8];

for(int i=6; i<jpegPixels.length-7; i++)
  {
     for(int j=6; j<jpegPixels[0].length-7; j++)
     {
       for(int x=0; x<2; x++)
       {  
        //************  ROW 1  ******************
        //********** Pixel 1 ********************
           pixelMatrix[0][0] = jpegPixels[i-1][j-1][x];

           //********** Pixel 2 ********************
           pixelMatrix[0][1] = jpegPixels[i-1][j][x];          

        //********** Pixel 3 ********************
           pixelMatrix[0][2] = jpegPixels[i-1][j+1][x];

        //********** Pixel 4 ********************
           pixelMatrix[0][3] = jpegPixels[i-1][j+2][x];

           //********** Pixel 5 ********************
           pixelMatrix[0][4] = jpegPixels[i-1][j+3][x];          

           //********** Pixel 6 ********************
           pixelMatrix[0][5] = jpegPixels[i-1][j+4][x];          

        //********** Pixel 7 ********************
           pixelMatrix[0][6] = jpegPixels[i-1][j+5][x];

        //********** Pixel 8 ********************
           pixelMatrix[0][7] = jpegPixels[i-1][j+6][x];

        //************  ROW 2  ******************
        //********** Pixel 9 ********************
           pixelMatrix[1][0] = jpegPixels[i][j-1][x];

           //********** Pixel 10 ********************
           pixelMatrix[1][1] = jpegPixels[i][j][x];

        //********** Pixel 11 ********************
           pixelMatrix[1][2] = jpegPixels[i][j+1][x];

           //********** Pixel 12 ********************
           pixelMatrix[1][3] = jpegPixels[i][j+2][x];

        //********** Pixel 13 ********************
           pixelMatrix[1][4] = jpegPixels[i][j+3][x];

           //********** Pixel 14 ********************
           pixelMatrix[1][5] = jpegPixels[i][j+4][x];

        //********** Pixel 15 ********************
           pixelMatrix[1][6] = jpegPixels[i][j+5][x];

           //********** Pixel 16 ********************
           pixelMatrix[1][7] = jpegPixels[i][j+6][x];

               //********** Pixel 17 - 64 ********************
               // ******* Too long to print the rest ********
          }
      }
 }
```

Can someone identify is this the correct way of grouping values into 8x8 blocks of a 3D array of h x w size? The reason is, is that when I  test print out values of the original pixels and resultant pixels, I am getting values from the resultant pixels from a higher ofset?

For e.g.: *Original pixels* - 2234445556788, *Resultant pixels* - 0000000002234445556788

Hope this is clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how your pixels are being represented in your example. So I chose to use the way that a pixel is represented by the BufferedImage class as per [this tutorial](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/graphics/bufferedimage_setrgb.shtml). If you need to change the way the pixels are being represented as ints you can edit the getIntFromPixel method.

```
private int getIntFromPixel(int[] pixel) 
{
    int r = pixel[0];
    int g = pixel[1];
    int b = pixel[2];

    return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}

// Returns the sub array with upper-left corner at [start_i][start_j] with
// width sub_w and height sub_h.
public int[][] getSubArray(int[][][] pixelArray, int start_i, int start_j
                               , int sub_w, int sub_h)
{       
    int[][] subArray = new int[sub_w][sub_h];

    for (int i = 0; i < sub_w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sub_h ; j++) {
            subArray[i][j] = getIntFromPixel(pixelArray[start_i + i][start_j + j]);
        }
    }

    return subArray;
}
```

Now for example given a 3x3 array

```
pixelArray = {
{{1,1,1}, {2,2,2}, {3,3,3}},
{{4,4,4}, {5,5,5}, {6,6,6}},
{{7,7,7}, {8,8,8}, {9,9,9}}
}
```

If we want to get the 2x2 pixel sub-array at [0][0]:

```
{{{1,1,1}, {2,2,2}}, {{4,4,4}, {5,5,5}}}
```

you can call

```
getSubArray(pixel, 0, 0, 2, 2);
```

Which returns the array

```
{{65793, 131586}, {263172, 328965}}
```

In your loop in the inner loop the pixelMatrix is being over written each time the 
loop iterates meaning that the contents of pixelMatrix will be the b value of the pixel.

Comment: OK thanks for your reply. I don't need to use bit shifting to get the pixel integer until further down the loop. So I can use getSubArray method to group 8 x 8 pixels? I hav'nt yet tested your method, but I could just simply assign pixelArray[start_i + i][start_j + j] instead of calling the getIntFromPixel method to just use each color component separately? Overall, your idea seems very legit.

Comment: In that case since you would need to store all three rgb values you need the getSubArray method to return a 3 dimensional array. Which would be an 8x8 array with each cell containing a 3 element array to represent the rgb values of the pixel. You then need to use System.arraycopy(pixelArray[start_i + i][start_j + j], 2, subArray[i][j], 0, 3); to copy each pixel over to the sub array.

Comment: I could ask one question...How could I go about using the 8x8 (or sub_w X sub_h) and reconstruct it back into the array of pixels?It would be the inverse of the getSubArray() method, right? Thanks

Comment: To copy it back instead of reading from the pixelArray on the line subArray[i][j] = getIntFromPixel(pixelArray[start_i + i][start_j + j]);. You can write to the pixelArray instead, so ya essentially the inverse.

Comment: Cool. I am probably over complicating it, but how can I sub array the next block, say 8x8. I don't think this could work: getSubArray(pixel, 8, 8, 8, 8); ? This is trying to get the second block of 8x8, but that would start from the 8th row, 8th column, right? I presumably would need a counter variable to get it incremented by 8 everytime? Thanks

Comment: To get all of the 8x8 blocks out of the pixelArray you would need to have two for loops. The outer one incrementing by 8 each time and iterating over the rows of the array and the inner one incrementing by 8 each time iterating over the columns of the array. This way you get the sub array with upper left corners at [0][0], [0][8], [0][16] ... [8][0], [8][8], [8][16] ... [m-8][n-8].